# javascript alert like gmail chat on chat updation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want Popups on new chat or popups when chat updated like gmail...
For Example if I am on other tab and gmail chat is updated then it shows on title..
I just want this type of code which shows when my database is updated or after every 10 seconds and once I clicked on it then it should not show again and again....

Comment: What about using Growl-like popups? http://webtoolkit4.me/2009/08/13/jquery-growl-likenotification-systems/

Answer (score 0):

I once write an plugin for html5 Notification, with it you can create an notification easily:

```
/**
 *  Notification
 *  @author:    ijse
 *  @require:   Chrome10+
 *  @params:    Same as webkitNotifications.create[HTML]Notification()
 *  @usage:
 *      new Notify("http://www.baidu.com").onshow(function() {
 *              alert("show");
 *          }).onclose(function() {
 *              alert("close");
 *          }).show();
 */
window.Notify = function() {
    var _params = arguments;
    // Validate arguments
    if(_params.length == 0) {
        console.error("Notify need at least one argument");
        return ;
    }
    // Check browser support
    if(!window.webkitNotifications) {
        console.error("Your browser does not support webkitNotifications feature!!");
        return ;
    }

    var _onclose, _onclick, _onerror, _onshow;
    var _notification, _replaceId, _showFlag = false;

    function bindEvents() {
        // Add event listeners
        // In W3C, display event is called show
        _notification.addEventListener("display", _onshow, false);
        _notification.addEventListener("click", _onclick, false);
        _notification.addEventListener("error", _onerror, false);
        _notification.addEventListener("close", _onclose, false);

        if(_replaceId)
            _notification.replaceId = _replaceId;
        // !!IMPORTANT&&WEIRD!! remove next line no events will work
        var t = _notification;
    }
    function createfn(permission) {
        // About permission on Chrome:
        //      PERMISSION_ALLOWED (0) indicates that the user has granted permission to scripts with this origin to show notifications.
        //      PERMISSION_NOT_ALLOWED (1) indicates that the user has not taken an action regarding notifications for scripts from this origin.
        //      PERMISSION_DENIED (2) indicates that the user has explicitly blocked scripts with this origin from showing notifications.
        if(permission == 0) {
            // If permission is allowed
            // Create notification
            if(_params.length == 1)
                _notification = window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(_params[0]);
            else
                _notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(_params[0],_params[1],_params[2]);

            // Bind events
            bindEvents();

            // Show, if yes flag
            !!_showFlag && _notification.show();
        } else {
            if(_onerror)
                _onerror.call(this);
            console.error("Notification permission is denied!!");
        }
    }

    // If permission already allowed, do not require again
    if(window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() != 0) {
        // Require permission from user
        window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission(function() {
            createfn.call(this, window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission());
        });
    } else {
        createfn.call(this, window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission());
    }

    // Return handler methods
    return {
        onclose: function(fn) { _onclose = fn; return this; },
        onclick: function(fn) { _onclick = fn; return this; },
        onerror: function(fn) { _onerror = fn; return this; },
        onshow : function(fn) { _onshow  = fn; return this; },

        show: function(replaceId) {
            _replaceId = replaceId;
            if(_notification) {
                // Notification already been created
                bindEvents();
                _notification.show();
            } else {
                // Flag yes to show
                _showFlag = true;
            }
            return _notification;
        },
        cancel: function() {
            _notification.cancel();
        }
    } // return handler
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of javascript you can use ajax function that calls a php page. use an array to accumulate all the messages. you said you are checking that page for every 10 seconds. display the array values in the chat window. then reset the array to empty. Then do the same process again. Hope this concept will work. I am not sure. If you want this in javascript. you should use the values in js array.